# Mongodb aggregate $lookup and group is very very slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am using aggregate on mongodb.
This aggregate gets the number of documents that are matched to "user.isLogin : true".

```
db.getCollection('example').aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "userId",
    foreignField: "userId",
    as: "user"
    }
},
{$match: {user.isLogin : true}},
{$unwind:user}
{ $count: "total_count" }
])
```

This aggregate takes more than 4 seconds now.
When I remove the $count, it takes 0.064 secs.

How can I speed up to 0.173 secs when I am using the $count?
I know $count is same to $group:{_id: null, total_count:{$sum: 1}} so this question is how to speed up the $group stage after $lookup stage?

Thanks, all.

Comment: Without $count, the database needs to return up to batch size of results, thus it doesn't have to calculate the full result set. With $count the database must calculate the full result set even though the output is smaller (one number instead of many documents).

Comment: Your saying is beyond for me. So what is the solution?
How can we reduce the time of lookup and group aggregation?
Is this mongo aggregation critical bug?

Answer (score 0):

Swap `$match` with `$lookup`. When you `$lookup` first, you are looking up all the documents first and then you are filtering them. If you filter them first, the number of looked up documents is reduced, so the performance improves.

Comment: I should add lookup first before match because match is using the looked up and joined object. Thanks for your first advice